# random bounce direction in Cocoa?

Tags: ios, random, uiimageview

I have `UIImageView` (ball) and it moves around the screen but I want it to bounce in a random direction off a specific image (named computer.paddle)

This is my code:

```
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect (ball.frame, computerPaddle.frame)) {
        if (ball.center.x < computerPaddle.center.x) {
            (ballVelocity.x =- ballVelocity.x);
        }
    }
```

NB I am using the rotation landscape right and I want it to bounce of the right side of the paddle to the right.
I am happy to make any `UIIntegers` or any thing else that is needed.

Comment: If you want a random direction, I'm guessing you're going to need a little y somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify.

Comment: So when the ball bounces off the computerPaddle it bounces off normal eg angle of incidence = angle of reflection. But, I would like it to bounce off in a random direction eg angle of incidence = angle of reflection + random number. How would I code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line in the inner block:

```
ballVelocity.y += arc4random() % (2 * MAX_VARIANCE) - MAX_VARIANCE;
```

`MAX_VARIANCE`, in this case, is the maximum amount of variation you want from the "normal" value of `ballVelocity.y`.  If you need a finer degree of variation, you can increase `MAX_VARIANCE` by some double `k` and multiply the expression by `1/k`.  For example,

```
ballVelocity.y += (arc4random() % (2*100*MAX_VARIANCE) - 100*MAX_VARIANCE)*0.01;
```

Comment: it took a little fiddling but i got there with the help of the second code. thx!!!